# Stored function with loop returns consisted of more than one row?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

The following stored function is returning:
'#1172 - Result consisted of more than one row'

What am I doing wrong?

It's a Stored function, with no params and expects an int to return.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE l_user_id INT;

    sloop:LOOP
        SELECT `user_id` INTO `l_user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `area_id` = 1;

    INSERT INTO `user_function_hours` SET `function_hour_id` = 1, `user_id` = l_user_id;
    INSERT INTO `user_function_hours` SET `function_hour_id` = 2, `user_id` = l_user_id;
    INSERT INTO `user_function_hours` SET `function_hour_id` = 3, `user_id` = l_user_id;
    INSERT INTO `user_function_hours` SET `function_hour_id` = 4, `user_id` = l_user_id;
    INSERT INTO `user_function_hours` SET `function_hour_id` = 5, `user_id` = l_user_id;
    END LOOP sloop;

    RETURN 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we will face this kind of errors in triggers.

Please check this query. It provides more than 1 records as result.

```
SELECT `user_id` INTO `l_user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `area_id` = 1;
```

Please change this query as,

```
SELECT `user_id` INTO `l_user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `area_id` = 1 LIMIT 1;
```

So that, you can solve this error.

Comment: Ah, I see what I'm doing wrong. I wanted to iterate through the result. But I just loop now. thanks for the eye openenr.

Comment: Needed to use a cursor instead of select into.